# We have a webapp done in Angular 4.0 with node 6. Should we upgrade to Angular 14 or 16

Tags: node.js, angular, upgrade, migrate

We have a webapp done in Angular 4.0 with node 6. Should we upgrade to Angular 14 or 16

We need to upgrade this app due to many CVEs reported on older framework.

So we definitely understand there will be many breaking changes, wondering should we go to
Angular 14 - to minimize breaking change effect
Angular 16 or Angular 17

We tried doing selective upgrades of dependencies/packages/sciprs that have CVEs reported, but it seems to force us to move to newer version of Angular

Comment: If you get to 14, you can go to latests, biggest hurdles is around 8-9 cause the render engine changed around then. However you probably gonna get hid more by typescript strictness as you have to go over it.